# php does not send correct stuff to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xampp

Hi guys I am learning PHP and the code below  sends information to my MySQL database but it does not match with the data i just gave him to insert, for example it inserts              1|blank|blank for the code below. I can´t solve it :

**insert.php file:**

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security


$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['firstname']);
$age = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['age']);

$sql="INSERT INTO Person (PID,Name, Age)
VALUES ('1','$firstname', '$age')";


if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added to database";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

It keeps me saying this:

```
Notice: Undefined index: firstname in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\Bioinformatics\insert.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined index: age in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\Bioinformatics\insert.php on line 12
```

**code for html form:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form name="input" action="insert.PHP" method="get">
First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Ronaldo"><br>
Age: <input type="text" name="Age" value="28"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 



</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help guys!

Comment: cause  $_POST['firstname'] and $_POST['age'] not have values

Comment: Because `$_POST['firstname']` and `$_POST['age']` doesn't contain any values.

Comment: your post values aren't set, are you using the GET method instead in your form maybe?

Comment: Where is your `form`? Please share the code of your `form` page too.

Comment: @TheRealHamza he is using `mysqli_` which still is supported.

Comment: @Gunaseelan..There is no any errors with the query.

Comment: @Gunaseelan..The error is surely because she/he is not getting the values for the variables as it is not defined.

Comment: Have you check whether form is submitted like if (!empty($_POST)){}

Comment: i have edited the question with html form and example of MySQL insertion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cause you have not values for `$_POST['firstname']` and `$_POST['age']` try to check it's have values or not.

```
if(!empty($_POST['Firstname'])) {
  $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Firstname']);
}
else {
  echo 'firstname empty';
}
if(!empty($_POST['Age'])) {
  $age= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Age']);
}
else {
  echo 'age empty';
}
```

also same for age
For check post values try `print_r($_POST);` on this page

Comment: You are right it says it's empty for both variables. I can´t understand why and how to solve it. For print_r it shows: Array
(
    [firstName] => Ronaldo
    [age] => 28

Comment: cause you need to use Firstname and Age instead of firstname and age use same exact name

Comment: Variables are still empty :s

Comment: try to change form method to POST <form name="input" action="insert.php" method="post">

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have forgotten to post the needed data. 
$_POST['firstname'] and $_POST['age'] are not defined in your html.
You are missing the following inputs or have misspelled them:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" />
<input type="text" name="age" />
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['firstname']);
$age = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['age']);
```

to

```
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'] ? mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['firstname']) : "";
$age = $_POST['age'] ? mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['age']) : "";
```

Answer (score 0):

`echo "<pre>";print_r($_REQUEST);exit;`  // to check values in all variable.

Place your php code below html code to get rid of undefined index notices or use isset() function eg. **if(isset($_POST['age']))** or initialize those variables with null value. like **$age = "";**

also see answer by @karlingen